# Change the color of one text in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change the color of the text when it is clicked.
So far I only figured out how to change the color of all items in the actionbar, but not for a certain one.

This is my actionbar.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/delObjs"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/history"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/settings"/>
<item android:id="@+id/demo"
     android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/demo"
    ></item>
```

So there are three attributes in my actionbar history,settings and demo.
If I click one of them its color should change.

Comment: Can you be more specific: which text are you trying to change? Is it something in your layout? Is it something on the actions bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about a Textview you can simply apply onClickListener on the Textview and change the color in the onClick method.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_id);

textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View view) {

   //Your code, you can use a switch if you have multiple textviews

}
});
```

EDIT

res/values/colors.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>

 <color name="orange_base">#BD9B35</color>
 <color name="orange_stroke">#BA8C00</color>
 <color name="orange_start">#E0C265</color>
 <color name="orange_end">#DEAA10</color>

 </resources>
```

and a example for a selector is

res/drawable/anyname.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@colors/yellow"/>
<item android:color="@colors/red"/>
</selector>
```

add this in your style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/action_item_text_color</item>
 </style>
```

then in the ActionBar you can just use the

```
 style="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: No, about the text in the actionbar, like settings,history.
If I click on settings, I want the word to change its color.

Comment: then you can declare a style and use a selector to do that

Comment: So I have to create a color folder in res/values and paste the code
 below R.color.action_item_text_color[...]
in it and change my style,right?

Comment: i am really sorry , i re read that post...you will have to create a colors folder here..You are right

Comment: uhm don't I have to identify the items so it knows which one to change?
It still changes the color of all the items in the actionbar

Comment: try using this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style
 to see the styles you can change and this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html by using 

     android:actionDropDownStyle